# How to add class to the next `ul` element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I select the second `ul` who has class `collapse` and add or remove (if is added) class.
But first I need to add `active` class to `li`element from first `ul` like I did it with this part of code.

`$(this).parent("ul#sidebarnav").length === 0
     ? $(this).addClass("active")
     : $(this).addClass("selected");`

I know that I can something like this `$(this).next("ul").addClass("in");` but I can't figure out where to add this part of code or do I need something plus or something else.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="sidebar-nav">
   <ul id="sidebarnav">
        <li> 
            <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="{{route('quotation.index')}}" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="fas fa-paste"></i>
                         <span class="hide-menu">Quotations</span>
            </a>
            <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">

                 <li>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                 </li>
                 ...
                 ...
             </ul>
```

**UPDATE:**
**jQuery**

```
var url = window.location + "";
    var path = url.replace(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/", "");
    var element = $('ul#sidebarnav a').filter(function() {
        return this.href === url || this.href === path;// || url.href.indexOf(this.href) === 0;
    });

    element.parentsUntil(".sidebar-nav").each(function (index)
    {
        if($(this).is("li") && $(this).children("a").length !== 0)
        {
            $(this).parent("ul#sidebarnav").length === 0
                ? $(this).addClass("active")
                : $(this).addClass("selected");
        }
        else if(!$(this).is("ul") && $(this).children("a").length === 0)
        {
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        }
        else if($(this).is("ul")){
            $(this).show();
        }
    });

    element.addClass("active");
    $('#sidebarnav a').on('click', function (e) {

        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
            $("ul", $(this).parents("ul:first")).removeClass("in");
            $("a", $(this).parents("ul:first")).removeClass("active");

            // open our new menu and add the open class
            $(this).next("ul").addClass("in");
            $(this).addClass("active");

        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $(this).parents("ul:first").removeClass("active");
            $(this).next("ul").removeClass("in");
        }
    })
    $('#sidebarnav >li >a.has-arrow').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: first you should paste complete code not half.

Comment: OK I update the jquery code

Comment: post the minified version of your code or use snipet instead

Answer (score 0):

Here will be few code snippet how you can get your desire result.

```
const data = document.querySelectorAll("ul.collapse");
```

this line will give you list of all the ul who have collapse class and this will be array. Now you want to remove collapse class from the second ul which has collapse class. (here is tricky you said all those ul who have collapse class so it will contains all those ul who have collapse class, and you said => "and add or remove (if is added)" <= so we will only need remove because all the ul will have collapse class, however i put condition just for your understanding in case collapse class not present first condition will add and second condition will remove if collapse is present.)

```
if (data[1].classList.indexOf("collapse") === -1 {
   data[1].classList.add("collapse");
}
else {
   data[1].classList.remove(" collapse ");
}
```

same you can add active class.